# Sql query to show Student data for the quarters of the year

Tags: sql-server

I want to generate the Student Data Comparison report where the data for the students is compared. Below are screenshots of the tables from where i want to fetch the data.
[image]

[image]

I want to compare the student data for the different quarters of the year. While generating the report the user can select any year and any number of columns to compare, the format of the report should like the below columns:

#### First Name    Last Name     2013 - 1 AssessmentA1    2013 - 2 AssessmentA1      2013 - 3 AssessmentA1      2013 - 4 AssessmentA1

In the above columns 2013 is the year column 1 is the quarter
Can anyone please let me know, how to achieve the above data using sql query?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to a column for ever possible year/quarter/assement combination, you have a problem. The SQL language *really* wants to know how many columns and of what kind will be in the results before it begins to execute the query. You can mitigate this some with PIVOT's, but you can't really avoid it unless you're willing to write dynamic sql.

If you limit yourself to one year, allow each year to have it's own set of rows, or are wanting to use an aggregate function like SUM() or AVG() for the assessment scores, you can do something with self joins, like this:

```
 SELECT q1.StudentID, s.FirstName, s.LastName, s.IsActive
    q1.AssessmentA1 AS [2013 - 1 AssessmentA1], q2.AssessmentA1 AS [2013 - 2 AssessmentA1]
 FROM Assements q1
 INNER JOIN Assements q2 ON q2.Year = q1.Year and q2.Quarter = 2 and q2.StudentID = q1.StudentID
 INNER JOIN Assements q3 ON q3.Year = q1.Year and q3.Quarter = 3 and q3.StudentID = q1.StudentID
 INNER JOIN Assements q4 ON q4.Year = q1.Year and q4.Quarter = 4 and q4.StudentID = q1.StudentID
 INNER JOIN Students s on s.ID = q1.StudentID
 WHERE q1.Quarter = 1
     AND Year=2013
```

Again, I need more information about how you want to handle your year groups to give you a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in my case columns and years are dynamic, so may be i have to do it in my code end.